# Connecting SSMS via P2S VPN with an Azure Active Directory account with MFA

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, ssms, azure-vpn

I have created an SQL Database on Azure. To secure the connection, I use a P2S VPN with an own certificate. The connection is established and tested. In SSMS the SQL Server Authentication works fine. I have entered the private IP address from the vNIC (10.1.1.4) and trusted the server certificate and checked "always encrypted in the advanced settings. Now, I want to log in with my Azure Active Directory accounts and it does not work. Here is the error message:

TITLE: Connect to Server ------------------------------ Cannot connect to 10.1.1.4. ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: Cannot open server "10.1.1.4" requested by the login. The login failed. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40532) For help, click: docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/… ------------------------------ BUTTONS: OK

Disconnecting the VPN and allow public connections on the SQL server works.

Answer (score 0):

For Login failed issues, it could be due to AAD.
Please try to reset the Active Directory passwords and try again.